# Sourcesets causes: app/AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist error

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, source-sets

I have 4 product flavours.  I am looking to set the source sets in order to assign the correct app name string and launcher Icon..

here is my gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.testing"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.0.4"
}

productFlavors{

    flavour1{
        applicationId "com.etlie.stockclient.flavour1"
    }

    flavour2{
        applicationId "com.etlie.stockclient.flavour2"
    }

    flavour3{
        applicationId "com.etlie.stockclient.flavour3"
    }

    flavour4{
        applicationId "com.etlie.stockclient.flavour4"
    }
}

sourceSets{
    main{
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    flavour1{
        res.srcDir 'variants/flavour1/res'
    }

    flavour2{
        res.srcDir 'variants/flavour2/res'
    }

    flavour3{
        res.srcDir 'variants/flavour3/res'
    }
    flavour4{
        res.srcDir 'variants/flavour4/res'
    }
}
```

Here is the product structure:

```
app
--java
--main
 |__AndroidManifest
--variant
 |__flavour1
   |__drawable-hdpi
   |__drawable-xhdpi
   |__drawable-xxhdpi
   |__values
 |__flavour2
   |__drawable-hdpi
   |__drawable-xhdpi
   |__drawable-xxhdpi
   |__values
 |__flavour3
   |__drawable-hdpi
   |__drawable-xhdpi
   |__drawable-xxhdpi
   |__values
 |__flavour4
   |__drawable-hdpi
   |__drawable-xhdpi
   |__drawable-xxhdpi
   |__values
```

So the project structure has changed, but the location of the AndroidManifest.xml hasn't.  If anyone knows how to fix this error I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score -1):

Provide the full path (from your module's `build.gradle` file) to your manifest:

```
manifest.srcFile 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

The default project structure is different though, so for me its `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I do that i get another error `Error:(25, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').`  This relates to the manifest file.

Comment: @DJ-DOO this seems like an unrelated issue to your current question.